# SSE: 'onmessage' never gets called

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events, eventsource

I'm following the most simple tutorials on the internet about how to listen to Server-Sent Events from Javascript:

```
var es = new EventSource('url')
es.onmessage = function (e) { console.log(e.data) }
```

But my `message` handlers never get called. `onopen` and `onerror` handlers do get called, Chrome Developer Tools do show a nice "stream" view of the events being sent by the server and if I do the same call from `curl` I get a stream of events nicely formatted in the correct way. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just realized, from [this tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-eventname), that you can associate an event name with each server-sent event.

When you do that, the `message` listener stops getting called and instead you have to setup a new special listener for each kind of event you're sending. I was doing that on my server.

So instead of `es.onmessage = function () {...}` I had to do `es.addEventListener("special-event-name", function () {...})`.

Comment: You can have the `message` listener and listeners for each of your custom events, too.

Comment: That's not how it is working for me. But if you believe that is true please answer the original question.

Comment: See my separate answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example showing how you can get the default `message` event type and a custom event type on the same SSE stream.

```js
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="payload"></div>
    <script>

      const stream = new EventSource('https://url-goes-here');

      stream.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        document.getElementById('payload').innerText = `Received a regular message: ${event.data}`;
      }, false);

      stream.addEventListener('myEvent', (event) => {
        document.getElementById('payload').innerText = `Received a myEvent message: ${event.data}`;
      }, false);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that much before creating this question, it didn't work.

Comment: Now I realized you're talking about different messages in the same stream! Then it could work. But if your message is tagged as `myEvent` then it won't be handled by `onmessage`.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. No, `onmessage` only handles the default message type `message`. That's why you add an event listener explicitly for the event types you care about.